# Related to SNR when the channel is in the form of vector and matrix

Tags: digital-communications, signal-detection, snr

In my system model there is a sensor (transmitter) with $M$ antennas and receiver with $Q$ antennas. The received signal expression is

$y_q(n) = (h_q+\textbf{f}_q\textbf{G}$)$s(n)$+$w_q(n)$----(1)

where $\textbf{f}_q = [f_{q,1}, f_{q,2},...,f_{q,M}]$ and $\textbf{G} = \text{diag}(g_1,g_2,...,g_M)$, $w_q(n)$ is AWGN such that $w_q(n)\sim\mathcal{C}\mathcal{N}(0,N_w)$.

All the channels i.e., $h,\textbf{f}$ and $\textbf{G}$ are zero mean circularly symmetric complex Gaussian random variables with respective variances. Also all these channels are i.i.d.

My query is how to form SNR for the eq.(1). I am getting confused as the channel includes vector as well as Matrix.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The vector times the diagonal matrix is another diagonal matrix. Find the variance of the product of two circularly symmetric gaussians and proceed from there.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your answer....